# VS 2013 - Linked libraries, but still get unresolved external symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to compile a `.dll` ([JAssimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/tree/master/port/jassimp) specifically)

I made a new Win32 project in VS2013, and added the correct header files to it (`jassimp.cpp`, `jassimp.h`).

I have also downloaded the binaries for Assimp, and that is where I set the `include` and `lib` directories.

More specifically, I went into Project -> Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Include Directories, and added `...\assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries\include` to the field.

I then went to Library Directories, and added `...\assimp-3.1.1-win-binaries\lib32` to the field.

Then, I went to Project -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, and added `assimp.lib` to the field.

However, I still get unresolved external errors; specifically:

```
1>jassimp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiImportFile referenced in function "class _jobject * __stdcall Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jclass *,class _jstring *,__int64)" (?Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile@@YGPAV_jobject@@PAUJNIEnv_@@PAV_jclass@@PAV_jstring@@_J@Z)
1>jassimp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiReleaseImport referenced in function "class _jobject * __stdcall Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jclass *,class _jstring *,__int64)" (?Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile@@YGPAV_jobject@@PAUJNIEnv_@@PAV_jclass@@PAV_jstring@@_J@Z)
1>jassimp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _aiGetErrorString referenced in function "class _jobject * __stdcall Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile(struct JNIEnv_ *,class _jclass *,class _jstring *,__int64)" (?Java_jassimp_Jassimp_aiImportFile@@YGPAV_jobject@@PAUJNIEnv_@@PAV_jclass@@PAV_jstring@@_J@Z)
```

How can I fix this, what am I doing wrong?